# Is slab allocator used to allocate memory for thunks in GHC?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, functional-programming, ghc, lazy-evaluation

Is any slab allocator or something similar used to allocate memory for thunk structures in GHC? Or, does it use something naive like `malloc` in C?

I guess number of thunks are allocated within a short time in lazy functional programming languages especially when multiple threads are running on them. Or, don't the allocations occur so often? I tried looking for code for it in [the GHC repository](https://github.com/ghc/ghc) but couldn't find any.

Comment: [Relevant paper on GHC's garbage collector](http://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/parallel-gc.pdf).

Comment: Memory allocation for garbage collected envrionments is often radically different from the way you would do things in C. The reason `malloc` is so expensive is because objects can be freed in any order but cannot be moved.  However, it's common for garbage collectors to move objects, which means you can make the allocator itself much, much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC uses a custom allocator, descibed here: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/BlockAlloc

It's based on blocks. If you're interested in how GHC manages its memory, https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

Allocation of thunks and other normal, small allocations are "open coded" during translation to Cmm, GHC's low-level intermediate language, and look something like

```
       Hp = Hp + 16;
       if (Hp > HpLim) goto cV2; else goto cV1;
   cV2:
       HpAlloc = 16;
       /* jump to garbage collector */
   cV1:
       /* Write to the newly-allocated memory and continue */
       /* ... */
```

`Hp` is a machine register that points to the last allocated word and `HpLim` is a memory location the upper limit of the current allocation area. `HpLim` can also be set to `0` to send a signal (e.g., an asynchronous exception or GC synchronization) to the thread. So, allocation is pretty cheap and also handles messaging.

Each Haskell capability (~ OS thread that executes Haskell code) has a separate "nursery" or allocation pool into which `Hp` points and which is delimited by `HpLim`. The block allocator mentioned in bennofs's answer is used to allocate these nurseries themselves and other large objects.